# Why does the W3C XML Schema specification allow integers to have leading zeros?

Tags: xsd, integer, w3c, specifications

Recently I had an example where in a xml message integer fields contained leading zeros. Unfortunately these zeros had relevance. One could argue why in the schema definition integer was chosen. But that is not my question. I was a little surprised leading zeros where allowed at all. So I looked up the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#integer) which of course told me the supertype is [decimal](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#decimal). But as expected specification don't really tell you why certain choices where made. So my question is really what is the rationale for allowing leading zeros at all? I mean numbers generally don't have leading zeros.

On a side note I guess the only way to add a restriction on leading zeros is by a pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My recollection is that the XML Schema working group allowed leading zeroes in XSD decimals because they are allowed in normal decimal notation:  1, 01, 001, 0001, etc. all denote the same number in normal numerical notation.  (But I don't actually remember that it was discussed at any length, so perhaps this is just my reason for believing it was the right thing to do and other WG members had other reasons for being satisfied with it.)

You are correct to suggest that the root of the problem is the use of xsd:integer as a type for a notation using strings of digits in which leading zeroes are significant (as for example in U.S. zip codes); I think you may be over-generous to say that one could argue about that decision.  What possible arguments could one bring forward in favor of such an obviously erroneous choice?

Comment: I agree with you on the decimals but the integer is a subtype. It is a more narrow, prohibiting the decimal point.

I do not understand your second point. Are you saying there is no argument for using xs:integer when leading zeros are relevant?

Comment: Yes, pretty much:  if leading zeroes are relevant, that's almost always a clue that the value is a string composed solely of decimal digits, and that normal arithmetic operations don't apply.  What would it mean to multiply two zip codes? To add them?  To compare them to decide which value was greater?  All clear indications that U.S. zip codes are strings over a restricted alphabet, not integers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although I remain to find it a bit strange. But I guess it is the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

Although numbers often doesn't have leading zeroes, parsing numbers almost always allows leading zeroes.

You don't want to disallow leading zeroes for numbers completely, because you want the option to write a number like `0.12` and not only like `.12`. As you want to allow at least one leading zero for floating point numbers, it would feel a bit restrictive to only allow one leading zero, and only for floating point numbers.

Sometimes numbers do have leading zeroes, for example the components in a date in ISO8601 format; `2014-05-02`. If you want to parse a component it's convenient if the leading zero is allowed, so that you don't have to write extra code to remove it before parsing.

The XML specification just uses the same sets of rules for parsing numbers that is generally used for most formats and in most programming languages.

Comment: I agree with you on the matter of decimals. But integer is a subtype of decimal. And by definition the only integer with a leading zero is zero itself.

You have a point on the matter of conforming to parsers. Although for integers I can't see the problem in specifying narrower than a parser can handle.

Comment: @pjanssen: That would make the parsing rules inconsistent, e.g. `01` is a valid floating point number, but would not be a valid integer value.

Comment: But is it not te be expected that a xs:integer field would contain only integers and no decimal/floating point numbers. Although this might be my lack of education on the matter speaking.

Comment: @pjanssen: The XML format is intended to be possible to read and edit manually, so the parsing rules are not as strict as possible. For example the sign is optional when it is positive so that you can write a number as `42` and don't have to write it as `+42`.